# How to implement a UI similar to Lollipop's recent apps UI?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, android-5.0-lollipop

I need to implement a UI which looks same as the UI used in Lollipop's recent apps .I'm attaching the screenshot .[image]

1) Can I implement it by extending any ViewGroup(AbsListview , AdapterView etc) and laying out the children accordingly with user swipe actions??

2) Am I not supposed to use 'Views' as each items , and use a screenshot of the 'View' as an item(Since Lollipop's items seems to be an image , rather than a 'View' , Google Chrome's tabs also have this same feature)?

3) Is it possible to figure out the implementation of this UI from Android 5 source code?

Comment: i am not sure, but it can be here (its just the result of 5 min searching, so i can be wrong): http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/recent/

Comment: @DerGolem Thanks for your reply . But I didn't find any 'View's which meets this requirement in latest support library

Comment: Have you tried the link i posted?

Comment: ve u got any possible solution

Answer (score 6):

I know it's late. But better late than never. I was also came across the similar requirement and found a library called [Material Recents](https://github.com/ZieIony/MaterialRecents), Which exactly does what you are looking for.

Comment: Wow. It is amazing library same like android lollipop recent apps, I like it

Comment: @Sanif, in fragment I made one layout and inside that I added this materialRecents but it is not at all showing any card data,showing empty card without any data.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look on how it is implemented in the source code. This application is part of the `com.android.systemui` package, which is part of the AOSP. The source code is available in the package [com.android.systemui.recents](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/59701b9ba5c453e327bc0e6873a9f6ff87a10391/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/recents).